# google map api and socket.io

Tags: javascript, google-maps, socket.io

I am getting lat and lng to my browser from a gps unit via socket.io like so:

```
        socket.on("web_latitude", function(msg) {
            document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML = msg
        })

        socket.on("web_longitude", function(msg) {
            document.getElementById("longitude").innerHTML = msg
        })
```

I have a google map like so:

```
    function initialize() {

      var mapOptions = {
        center: { lat: -46.85, lng: 150.644},
        marker: {lat: client_lat, lng:client_lng},
        zoom: 8
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

How in the world do I inject lat and lng into the map? I have tried combining functions however google maps seems to break if I add anything special to it which rules out scoping variables. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. make the map global
2. Check and see if both the latitude and longitude div's have useful values
3. Use those values to set the map position

```
var map;
function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    center: { lat: -46.85, lng: 150.644},
    marker: {lat: client_lat, lng:client_lng},
    zoom: 8
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}
socket.on("web_latitude", function (msg) {
  document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML = msg;
  setMap();
});

socket.on("web_longitude", function (msg) {
  document.getElementById("longitude").innerHTML = msg;
  setMap();
});

function setMap() {
  if ((document.getElementById('latitude') != '') && (document.getElementById('longitude') != '')) {
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML),
      parseFloat(document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML)));
  }
}       
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```